# AngularJS get dashboard settings using $htttp before initializing a dashboard controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am still on a crash course with Angular. I am working on quite a complicated dashboard framework, all written in angular. Before I load the controllers, I need to get a bunch of dashboard settings from the server first using $HTTP. These settings are then used to control the layout of the dashboards. 
So I read the way angular builds is by first running config methods, then run methods, then the controllers.
I can't use $HTTP in a config method, so I have built this in my main.js:

```
    MetronicApp.run(['$rootScope','$http', function($rootScope,$http) {

  var CUID = Cookies("CUID");
  console.log('portlet settings for '+ CUID);
   $http.get('/myurl/V3_portlet_settings?p_user_id='+CUID)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log('portlet status: ' + response.status);
            $rootScope.$broadcast("dashSettings",response.data);
        });

}]);
```

When I run, this all works happily and I see the data in the console.

Then in my controller:

```
$scope.$on( "dashSettings", 
function(event,data){
    $scope.dData = data;
     console.log('dash data service identified in dash controller');
     console.log($scope.dData.count);
    } );
```

Couple of questions:

1. Is this the best way to get settings before initializing the dash. My plan would be to embed the calls that build the dash inside my $scope.$on block. I started looking at how to run a run method synchronously before the controllers initialize, but maybe I don't need to.
2. Any obvious idea why the $scope.$on method does not seem to fire?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I thinking [resolved dependencies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) is better - for when you go back to the dashboard from another state

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to place your `$http` functions in a service or factory and then resolve these in your controller.
The key here is the use of [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Angular documentation describes this as

> A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their
>   return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing

First create a service:

```
app.factory('DataService', function($http) {
  var getValues= function() {
    var url = '/myurl/V3_portlet_settings?p_user_id='+ CUID;
    return $http.jsonp(url) // returns a promise
  };

  return {
    getValues: getValues
  }
});
```

And then in your controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope, DataService) {     
    DataService.getValues().then( // resolve the promise using .then()
    function(data){
      // successcallback
      // you can now safely populate the data in you controller
      console.log(data);
    },
    function(error){
      // errorcallback
      console.log(error);
    })   
});
```

I think it is a better approach to use data services to handle data operations such as $http requests.
The return of promises allows for chaining of (multiple) promises and better handling of async calls. 
You might find [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#data-services) useful, especially the section about 'Separate Data Calls' (Y060) and 'Return a Promise from Data Calls' (Y061)

Comment: Thanks for the answer: I've already started down this road but hit a couple of obstacles. The issue I have is the settings are not dynamic, so I need to set those settings using ng-class before the HTML renders. Hence I need to ensure a settings feed is run and the JSON consumed before I build the dashboard. I'm not sure how I delay the rendering of HTML until a JSON feed is fetched?